# Create page tab using graph API php sdk - is this correct?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is this the correct way to use the php sdk `api` method to install a page tab?

```
$path = '/PAGE ID/tabs/';
$params = array(
     'app_id' => 'APP ID',
     'access_token' => 'ACCESS TOKEN'
);
$install = $facebook->api($path, 'POST', $params);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. I tried it and it works. Suerte